# Conditional Probability and independence

Tags: probability, probability-theory

so there's this following problem:

Given the variables X and Z-X, that are independent and each distributed evenly on {-1, 1}, I need to find the probability that P(Z>=0). Now, the correct solution is different but I want to understand why mine is not.

I tried calculating the explicit distribution of Z the following way:

1/2 = (Z-X = 1) = P(Z-X=1|X=1) = P(Z=2)
where the first equality is from the even distribution, the second one is from independence and the third one is the one I think I made a mistake on, and I thought it was correct because given X = 1, Z-X = 1 if and only if Z = 2. why is this wrong?

thanks

Comment: $Z$ and $X$ are not independent.  $P(Z=2\,|\,X=1)=\frac 12$ but $P(Z=2\,|\,X=-1)=0$.

Comment: $P(Z-X=1\mid X=1)=P(Z=2\mid X=1) \neq P(Z=2)$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have no guarantee that $Z,X$ will be independent (and infact they are not).

Use the Law of Total Probability:
$$\mathsf P(Z=z) ~{= \mathsf P(Z=z,X=-1)+\mathsf P(Z=z,X=1) \\ = \mathsf P(Z-X=z+1, X=-1)+\mathsf P(Z-X=z-1, X=1)}$$

*Now* you have joint probabilities of independent random variables.